# Update gdal on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, gdal, ubuntu-22.04, gdal2tiles.py

I'm trying to update GDAL on my Ubuntu 22.04 :

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade GDAL`

This error occurs :

```
extensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp:3237:10: fatal error: ogr_recordbatch.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
       3237 | #include "ogr_recordbatch.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

"Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type" means no file or folder found in french.

OGR is installed and is working fine :

```
ogrinfo --version
GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
```

I am out of idea ...

Comment: For those having the same issue, my point was to use webp profil for map tiles which is only available in last version. Since i couldn't find a solution with the update of gdal, i used a php/shell script to convert all png files to webp with cwebp lib `cwebp -q 50 file.png -o file.webp`

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
If you have set up a virtual environment with Python and if in the given virtual environment you don't mind to downgrade your gdal Python library to fit the same version of your system (in our case GDAL version 3.4.1), simply install the same version of the library in your virtual environment with `pip install gdal==3.4.1`.
That worked fine for me.
However, I see that you are trying to upgrade GDAL, so probably you need some feature that is not available in 3.4.1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ogr_recordbatch.h` is one of the new include files in GDAL 3.6.0 - https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.6.0/NEWS.md

Obviously your system-installed GDAL from Ubuntu is an older version - 3.4.1.

I don't know what are you trying to do.

If you are trying to update only the Python module, it requires having an adequate system-installed GDAL. This can't work.

If you are trying to update the system-installed GDAL - Ubuntu does not have a current GDAL PPA.

You have two options if you need a current version:

- Get one of the official Docker images and use it in Docker
- Uninstall the Ubuntu system-install GDAL, get the source code and compile it yourself

Comment: I tried to compile latest GDAL version with cmake as suggested on their documentation but couldn't be successful, so much error to search for. I finally used vcpkg package with a usefull version for me : https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html.