# Install gdal in a docker python image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gdal

I'm trying to install gdal in a python **3.10.8** docker image from Cloud Build in Google Cloud but I cannot find any working solution so far. I have tried different approaches from the internet but I always receive the same error:

```
Step #0: Step 5/9 : ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/bin
Step #0:  ---> Running in 7b48f619d4a1
Step #0: Removing intermediate container 7b48f619d4a1
Step #0:  ---> b4313bd792ac
Step #0: Step 6/9 : ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/share/lintian/overrides/gdal-bin
Step #0:  ---> Running in 1745e30e8a86
Step #0: Removing intermediate container 1745e30e8a86
Step #0:  ---> 1f7ec2e34cd8
Step #0: Step 7/9 : ARG CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
Step #0:  ---> Running in 4d3ccf1e9efa
Step #0: Removing intermediate container 4d3ccf1e9efa
Step #0:  ---> 787d1acef1f3
Step #0: Step 8/9 : ARG C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
Step #0:  ---> Running in 00340d417631
Step #0: Removing intermediate container 00340d417631
Step #0:  ---> 1922c706cabe
Step #0: Step 9/9 : RUN pip install GDAL
Step #0:  ---> Running in 71a5e16d25d4
Step #0: Collecting GDAL
Step #0:   Downloading GDAL-3.7.0.tar.gz (775 kB)
Step #0:      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 775.5/775.5 kB 40.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Step #0:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Step #0:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Step #0:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
Step #0:   
Step #0:   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
Step #0:   │ exit code: 1
Step #0:   ╰─> [84 lines of output]
Step #0:       WARNING: numpy not available!  Array support will not be enabled
Step #0:       running egg_info
Step #0:       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5k_eohyx/GDAL.egg-info
Step #0:       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5k_eohyx/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
Step #0:       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5k_eohyx/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
Step #0:       writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5k_eohyx/GDAL.egg-info/requires.txt
Step #0:       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5k_eohyx/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
Step #0:       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-5k_eohyx/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Step #0:       Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #0:         File "/tmp/pip-install-2kmkdthm/gdal_7fd12a6a1cfc4f828e9ac25e1118c961/setup.py", line 87, in fetch_config
Step #0:           p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Step #0:         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
Step #0:           self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
Step #0:         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1847, in _execute_child
Step #0:           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
Step #0:       NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'gdal-config'
```

The dockerfile that I'm using is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.10.8-buster

#update pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/share/lintian/overrides/gdal-bin

ARG CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ARG C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN pip install GDAL
```

I tried to set up the PATH variable by myself but unfortunately I was unsuccessful.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Do I need to set some variable right or maybe install something more? Why is it asking for the **gdal-config** all the time? Shouldn't it look for the **gdal-bin**?

Comment: In which python version would it work? Which python version and which gdal version should I use to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem here is that you need the gdal-dev package if you expect to compile code that uses GDAL:

```
apt -y install libgdal-dev
```

However, after installing that you're going to run into additional problems, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74473006/update-gdal-on-ubuntu-22-04). The GDAL package in the python:3.10.8-buster image is only 2.4.0, and you need at least 3.6.0, or you need to install an older version of the python GDAL package.

---

You can alleviate this issue by using a more recent Python image, and making sure you install the Python `gdal` package corresponding to the version of `gdal` installed via `apt`:

```
$ docker run -it --rm python:3.11 bash
root@47dd9a0e2dc1:/# apt update
[...]
root@47dd9a0e2dc1:/# apt -y install libgdal-dev
[...]
root@47dd9a0e2dc1:/# pip install gdal==3.6.0
[...]
Installing collected packages: gdal
Successfully installed gdal-3.6.0
```

Comment: Well, it got past last error, but it failed to build a wheel for gdal, I applied what you suggested and also changed the image to `python:3.11-buster`. There is a huge error log that got generated from here which looks like a lot of stuff was not visible to gdal, do I need to set some ENV as well or download more? Log file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PHkfjDNCGtFHaSDgVgpNl0CDLPML0L-n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The `python:3.11-buster` image only has GDAL version 2.4.0, so I wouldn't expect that to work. Using the `python:3.11` image specified in this answer, I can successfully install the Python GDAL module and then `import osgeo` in Python.